# I ran into problems with `cmake..`

Tags: doxygen

Because of some requirements, I need to install doxygen on ubuntu 12.04, but I ran into problems with `cmake..`.

The error log as follow:

```
~/doxygen/build$ cmake ..
-- Found BISON: /usr/bin/bison (found version "2.7") 
-- The javacc executable not found, using existing files
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in liblodepng/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "lodepng" requires the language dialect "CXX14" (with compiler
  extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.


CMake Error in libmscgen/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "mscgen" requires the language dialect "CXX14" (with compiler
  extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.


CMake Error in libversion/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "doxygen_version" requires the language dialect "CXX14" (with
  compiler extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to
  enable it.
.
.
.
.
.
.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nfore/doxygen/build
```

@albert The problem has been resolved by update GCC into gcc-6 g++-6.
But I ran into new problems as follow:
clang version is Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3~precise2 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)

```
~/build$ cmake ..
~/build$ make
Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/doxymain.dir/context.cpp.o
In file included from /home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/context.h:20:0,
                 from /home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/context.cpp:19:
/home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/template.h:238:20: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘bool TemplateVariant::isValid() const’ is not a literal type
     constexpr bool isValid()    const { return m_variant.valid(); }
                    ^~~~~~~
/home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/template.h:92:7: note: ‘TemplateVariant’ is not literal because:
 class TemplateVariant
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/template.h:92:7: note:   ‘TemplateVariant’ has a non-trivial destructor
/home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/template.h:240:20: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘bool TemplateVariant::isBool() const’ is not a literal type
     constexpr bool isBool()     const { return m_variant.is<bool>(); }
.
.
.
/home/nfore/windows-kenny/doxygen/doxygen-1.9.2/src/template.h:311:27: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function ‘const char* TemplateVariant::typeAsString() const’ is not a literal type
     constexpr const char *typeAsString() const
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/doxymain.dir/context.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/doxymain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Quite obvious. Have you installed JDK?

Comment: @Raptor JDK? The message about JavaCC is just an info message signalling that javacc is not present but that doxygen will use the "precompiled" / translated *.cpp etc from the *.jj. JavaCC is not necessary for ordinary users, but only for developers / maintainers of the vhdl parser in doxygen. Furthermore also a specific version of JavaCC is necessary (as there might otherwise be some incompatibilities).

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is quite old (as far as I know and I think also the version of GCC will be quite old here and not have all required feature. Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @albert Yes it is, but due to some reason I need to do so. The version of GCC is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`

Comment: This version of gcc is indeed too old and doesn't have the required features for the recent doxygen vesrions.

Comment: @albert Thanks for your help! After I update GCC into gcc-6 g++-6, the problem has resolved.

Comment: I think that here we probably have a similar problem as with gcc it is too old.

Comment: After I update GCC into 9 as same as in Ubuntu 20.04, the problem still exist.
Then I compared the difference in the logs of `cmake ..` between Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 20.04, and I found that the clang version of the two is quite different. (`clang 3.4` `clang 10.0`). But I can't find any way to upgrade clang version of `ubuntu 12.04` to 10.0.